# Howto find a listitem which contains a specific substring

Tags: clojure

I have a list of strings, fx '("abc" "def" "gih") and i would like to be able to search the list for any items containing fx "ef" and get the item or index returned.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all the indexes of the matching positions along with the element you can try this:

```
(filter #(re-find #"ef" (second %)) (map-indexed vector '("abc" "def" "gih")))
=>([1 "def"])
```

`map-indexed vector` generates an index/value lazy sequence

```
user> (map-indexed vector '("abc" "def" "gih"))
  ([0 "abc"] [1 "def"] [2 "gih"])
```

Which you can then `filter` using a regular expression against the `second` element of each list member.

```
 #(re-find #"ef" (second %))
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining `filter` and `re-find` can do this nicely.

```
user> (def fx '("abc" "def" "gih")) 
#'user/fx

user> (filter (partial re-find #"ef") fx)
("def")

user> (filter (partial re-find #"a") fx)
("abc")
```

In this case I like to combine them with `partial` though defining an anonymous function works fine in that case as well. It is also useful to use `re-pattern` if you don't know the search string in advance:

```
user> (filter (partial re-find (re-pattern "a")) fx)
("abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just indices:

- Lazily:

  ```
  (keep-indexed #(if (re-find #"ef" %2)
                    %1) '("abc" "def" "gih"))
  => (1)
  ```
- Using loop/recur

  ```
  (loop [[str & strs] '("abc" "def" "gih")
         idx 0
         acc []]
    (if str
      (recur strs
             (inc idx)
             (cond-> acc
               (re-find #"ef" str) (conj idx)))
      acc))
  ```

  For just the element, refer to Arthur Ulfeldts answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a traditional recursive definition that returns the index.  It's easy to modify to return the corresponding string as well.

```
(defn strs-index [re lis] 
  (let [f (fn [ls n] 
             (cond 
               (empty? ls) nil 
               (re-find re (first ls)) n
               :else (recur (rest ls) (inc n))))]
    (f lis 0)))

user=> (strs-index #"de" ["abc" "def" "gih"])
1
user=> (strs-index #"ih" ["abc" "def" "gih"])
2
user=> (strs-index #"xy" ["abc" "def" "gih"])
nil
```

(Explanation: The helper function `f` is defined as a binding in `let`, and then is called at the end.  If the sequence of strings passed to it is not empty, it searches for the regular expression in the first element of the sequence and returns the index if it finds the string.  This uses the fact that `re-find`'s result counts as true unless it fails, in which case it returns `nil`.  If the previous steps don't succeed, the function starts over with the rest of the sequence and an incremented index.  If it gets to the end of the sequence, it returns nil.)

Comment: Excellent iteration example. More examples of this type for learning functional programming in lisp can be found at [sicp](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Comment: Why do you bind f in the loop?

Comment: (Wow, why'd I get a downvote?)   @Igrapenthin, `f` doesn't have to be defined in `loop`, course.  Often I define this sort of helper function a separate, named function, called for example, "strs-index-aux".  I think that's perfectly legitimate, and it might be easier to read.  Since the purpose of this function is only to do the work for strs-index, however, an option is to define the function with a local binding, so that it doesn't appear in the namespace.  Maybe that's not what you're asking about, though.  Not sure.

Comment: You could either use let instead of loop (the recur in f would still work), or make the body of f the loop body (the recur would recur the loop). Defining a loop that never recurs, with a recursive function literal as its only argument, is downright weird and totally pointless.

Comment: Ah, you're right @noisesmith.  I was slightly confused.  I had observed that it worked with `let` substituted for `loop`, but didn't understand why.  Now I understand (and why I got a downvote, too.)  I'll edit, replacing `loop` with `let`.